# Error when running "rails generate scaffold pins description:string"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, terminal, scaffold

I type the following code into the terminal:

```
rails generate scaffold pins description:string
```

and I get the following error:

```
Plural version of the model detected, using singularized version. Override with --force-plural.
      invoke  active_record
The name 'Pin' is either already used in your application or reserved by Ruby on Rails.
Please choose an alternative and run this generator again.
```

Why am I getting this error and what can I do to fix it?

I have been searching for a solution but I can't find any.

Comment: no ones gonna help me?

Comment: normally, in a scaffold, you give the singular version of the object to be build, in this case pin. That's where the first error comes from. The second error says it has been used already? A brief search didn't show "pin" as reserved word...

Comment: so what do you tihnk i should do?

Comment: Do a global search in all your sources on "Pin" (whole word). If you find it: bingo! If not, assume it's reserved, and choose a different word...

Answer (score 1):

In the console, run "rails destroy scaffold pins description:string"